# Connect to other pcs on the network from my VM

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running a Windows XP VM on my pc using VirtualBox using NAT configuration.
I can access the internet but unable to access any of the other PCs on the network.
One thing I noticed is my physical pc has an IP of something like 192.168.1.X but the VMs IP is 10..0.2.15. 
Do I need to do something else additionally?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access them specifying the IP address. You won't be able to access by the computer name because the VM is not in the same network as them.

In case it doesn't work or its not a good solution for you, use a Bridged Network instead of NAT. It will connect the VM Ethernet Adapter directly in the same network medium of the real machines to work in the same IP range and stuff.

Comment: Tried both options and still says the message, cant access the machine or any shares